# How to convert two dimensional array to one dimensional in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have output of array:

```
answers4 = [["1003"],["1002"],["1001"]]
```

But after using:

```
$answers5 = array_reduce($answers4, 'array_merge', array());
```

returns blank values: ["","",""]

I want return: answers5 = ["1003","1002","1001"]

Thank you for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are trying to flatten a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array. The array_reduce function in PHP should work perfectly for this, however, it seems you are dealing with array elements as arrays themselves, which is why you are not getting the expected output.

Since your sub-arrays contain strings instead of more arrays, you can use array_map and array_merge together like so:

```
$answers4 = [["1003"],["1002"],["1001"]];
$answers5 = array();

foreach ($answers4 as $answer) {
    $answers5 = array_merge($answers5, $answer);
}

print_r($answers5);
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1003
    [1] => 1002
    [2] => 1001
)
```

This basically loops through the main array, and for each sub-array, merges it with the result array, effectively flattening it. The elements of the inner arrays are directly appended to the result array in order.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, it function! Thank you.

Comment: Can you pass your entire code?

Comment: My wrong, its okay. :)